# Retrieve all Comments by UserId in Discussion Board

Tags: caml-query, csom, discussion-board

It try retrieving all Comments from a single person inside a discussion board. This is the CAML:

```
<View>
  <QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' /></QueryOptions>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE'/>
        <Value Type='Lookup'>10</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
  <ViewFields></ViewFields>
</View>
```

When looking at that List manually I can see that there are discussions with comments from the author with id "10"

But when I run this query all I retrieve is an empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this. Did not work with `QueryOptions`, but with

```
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
<Query>...</Query>
</View>
```

instead

Comment: Mark this as the answer so that the question can be closed.

Comment: I will. Just cannot until tomorrow :)